# How to initialize the variables in external RAM?

Tags: c, ram

```
typedef struct test {
       int a;
       int b;
       int c;
}_test;

 __ext_ram__ _test test1 = {0}; // Declared this global variable in external RAM
```

Do we need to use memset() for initializing it in external RAM?

```
memset(&test1, 0, sizeof(_test));
```

Comment: The C standard does not have the concept of "external ram". All this would be implementation-specific extensions. In order to get an answer you would need to specify the implementation you're using in the question itself!

Comment: What is `__ext_ram__`? how do you use it? what platform are you on? which compiler, compiler version and options are you using? What does the documentation of your compiler says about it?

Comment: What do you mean saying external RAM!? What's kind of hardware is the extenal RAM you would use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linker do this for you. So first you define your variable (i. e. your struct). After that you declare your variable and use the `section` argument to place the variable in a given section:

```
_test __attribute__((section (".ram"))) MyStruct;
```

Now you have to create/modify your linker script to place the section in your RAM:

```
MEMORY
{
  ...
  ram_data       (rwx) : ORIGIN = RAM_start_addr, LENGTH = section_length
  ...
}

SECTIONS
{
  ...

  .mySection section_address :
  {
    KEEP(*(.ram)) 
  } > ram_data

  ...
}
```

Compile it and your data is placed in RAM.

Comment: Or you could create a variable in the linker script and zero it out in C code.